# Woocommerce Follow Up Emails Plugin - email issue

Tags: email, woocommerce, cpanel

OK so im just gonna ask this question, as I am at the end of the rope, with hopes someone out there will have some advice.

I have installed the Woocommerce Follow Up Emails plugin on my site, and for the life of me I cannot get it send the email.

The settings I have are:

Trigger: 3 days after the order total is above $1.00

Setting: Customer recieves the email once

There is nothing in the "scheduled emails" of the plugin showing up, however and this is the part that throws me off, in the Tools>Scheduled Actions of the wordpress dashboard i get multiple entries of the below:

[image]

which tells me that it the emails are being scheduled but are not being sent out (even though it says, action complete). I have checked the WPMail log nothing, i have checked Cpanel Email Tracking and theres nothing. I have a WP Cron plugin installed that tells me it is functioning correctly.

Does anybody have any ideas/suggestions that i could do or check that I havent done already? Is there something I'm missing?

Any help will greatly be appreciated.

P.S, I purchased the plugin from a third party site and cant ask Woocommerce for support without paying for subscription (which i will do as my absolute last resort)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin works fine on my side, although it is very basic in its functionalities and you reach super quickly its limitations.

I'd suggest you buy the plugin from WC. They tend to have special offers of 30-50% off few times a year. Their support is typically very good and has a live chat so you get answers often directly.

Hope you got it figured out by now.